# How to track the last Variable of *ngFor in the ngForTrackBy function of Angular 2

Tags: angularjs, angular

If I use  *ngFor="let item of items; let i = index; let isLast=last"  I get the value of isLast in the UI by using {{isLast}}.
But if I use ngForTrackBy: myFunction , the function only support index:number and obj : any that contains the value of the item.

So How does one get the "last" Variable as stated in https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/NgFor-directive.html in the custom ngForTrackBy function?
Is it even possible?

Is there another way to track the even that *ngFor completed rendering, so I can limit the number of row shown with a scroll-able window?

Comment: What are your template which uses `ngForTrackBy` and the function itself?

Comment: The template part is:<tr *ngFor='let rp of DocumentsFiltered; trackBy:customTrackBy;' > and the function is:  customTrackBy(index: number, obj: any): any {
        debugger;
        console.log(last);
        return index;
    }

Comment: Please add this staff to the question and fix formatting. It's very hard to read and understand.